# How to check an IP address is within a range of two IPs in Python?

Tags: python, range, ip, subnet

I have an IP address and I'm given two other IP addresses which together creates an IP range. I want to check if the first IP address is within this range. How can i find that out in Python without using loops?

Comment: if you have the subnet mask of networks each IP and this first IP subnet mask is same or greater then this IP is within the range. If you don't have the subnet mask you can use binary AND to try to get network portion of the IP from there you can see if it's within range.

Comment: In what format are the ip's given?

Comment: In the event that it's an iterable, then `min_ip[0] <= cur_ip[0] < max_ip[0]` would tell you if a given series is within a range. This could then be expounded upon to determine if all values are matching

Comment: Can you show an example. the example IP range is 142.250.0.0 - 142.251.255.255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing the ip format so that we can compare

```
def convert_ipv4(ip):
    return tuple(int(n) for n in ip.split('.'))
```

This function will return True or False if the ip is within range or not

```
def check_ipv4_in(addr, start, end):
    return convert_ipv4(start) < convert_ipv4(addr) < convert_ipv4(end)



ip_range = ('1.1.0.0', '1.1.255.255')

print(check_ipv4_in('1.1.99.99', *ip_range))
```

It will print 'true' in this case as the function returns True in this case